# Prevent mod-rewrite from splitting URI

Tags: mod-rewrite

All --

On a reverse proxy, I'm trying to automatically append a querystring arg to the end of an incoming URI, and mod-rewrite seems to be doing something strange.

If I use rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    /t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard$    /t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard\?Language=3  [L,PT]
#####Proxy Rule
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://server8/
ProxyPassReverse / http://server8/
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

I see Apache kicking out the following using Fiddler:

```
http://192.168.203.34:9089/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard?Language=3
```

Good so far.

I also see the request arriving at the machine that the reverse proxy passes through to:

```
192.168.203.34 - - [19/Apr/2013:11:35:04 -0400] 80 "GET /t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard?Language=3 HTTP/1.1" "fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d, 192.168.203.34" 200 4052 "-" 109186 UXFkKMCoyx0AAAA0Q2UAAAEM
```

However, the app doing the work on the destination machine (192.168.203.29) doesn't respond correctly. Rather than rendering a report using a particular language, it hangs.

If I execute `http://192.168.203.29/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard?Language=3`  directly against the app server, the report renders fine. It appears to be the rewrite rule that is causing the problem.

Why? I see this in error.log:

```
[Fri Apr 19 10:55:55.194288 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 13240:tid 712] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d:32996] fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d - - [simpleprime/sid#982130][rid#dbcd50/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard
[Fri Apr 19 10:55:55.194288 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 13240:tid 712] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d:32996] fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d - - [simpleprime/sid#982130][rid#dbcd50/initial] applying pattern '/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard$' to uri '/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard'
[Fri Apr 19 10:55:55.194288 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 13240:tid 712] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d:32996] fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d - - [simpleprime/sid#982130][rid#dbcd50/initial] rewrite '/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard' -> '/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard?Language=3[L,PT]'
RIGHT HERE ->>>>[Fri Apr 19 10:55:55.194288 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 13240:tid 712] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d:32996] fe80::a53f:6156:2a22:378d - - [simpleprime/sid#982130][rid#dbcd50/initial] split uri=/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard?Language=3[L,PT] -> uri=/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard, args=Language=3[L,PT]**
```

If I simplify the rule and remove the ?Language=3, things works well:

```
RewriteRule    /t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard$    /t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard  [L,PT]
```

I can hit the reverse proxy with

```
http://192.168.203.34/t/SkunkWorks/views/LabelLocalization/Dashboard?Language=3
```

...and it is properly passed through to the 192.168.203.29 box. The machine renders the report as it should.

I'm guessing that the "URI SPLIT" thing is the cause of the problem...because things work when I don't see that in the error.log, and they break when I do.

Anything I can do to prevent the URI Split?

Comment: Have you tried removing the backslash before the query-string question mark? The target URL is not a regular expression, so you do not need to escape the question mark.

Comment: Yeah, I started w/o the escape...added it later to see if it made a difference.

Comment: Apache is sending the request to `192.168.203.34:9089` but you're testing against `192.168.203.29`. What if you request the `192.168.203.34:9089` address directly?